# GHC cannot infer type of function called from `ReaderT (Proxy p) IO ()`

Tags: haskell, type-inference

The following code compiles:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader
import Data.Proxy

f1 :: ReaderT (Proxy p) IO ()
f1 = f2

f2 = undefined
```

GHC knows type of `f1`:

```
> :t f1
f1 :: ReaderT (Proxy p) IO ()
```

But it can't figure out the type of `f2`:

```
> :t f2
f2 :: t
```

What's wrong?

My idea was to put `Proxy` inside a reader so that I do not have to pass it around. Is this a problem somehow?

Comment: The type of `f2` is `forall t. t` (the `forall` is implicit, so it is omitted when GHCi prints it). That is the type of `undefined`. `f2`'s type can't be constrained by how it is used. If that sort of thing happened, if you use `id 'a'` you could never use `id` on non-`Char` types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing's wrong. The type checker *did* figure out the type of `f2` - look at ghci's output again:

```
ghci> :t f2
f2 :: t
```

`t` is shorthand for `forall t. t`. `f2` can take on any type. That makes sense - `f2 = undefined` after all.

```
ghci> :t undefined
undefined :: a
```

When you write `f1 = f2`, you're using `f2` at the more specific type of `ReaderT (Proxy p) IO ()`. `ReaderT (Proxy p) IO ()` is one way to instantiate the type `t`. In other words, the type inference algorithm has generated the simple unification constraint `t ~ ReaderT (Proxy p) IO ()`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but it didn't get me closer to what I wanted. I think I misframed my actual question. I'm going to post another one.